Multi-line if expression in assignment context
I have this code:
output "output_value" {
  value = (
    data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id if 
    length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment) > 0 && 
    length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments) > 0 
    else null
  )
  description = "This is the output value"
)

terraform fmt gives me this error:
│ Error: Unbalanced parentheses
│
│   on path/to/my.tf line 16, in output "compartment_id":
│   15:   value = (
│   16:      data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id if
│
│ Expected a closing parenthesis to terminate the expression.
╵

╷
│ Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on path/to/my.tf line 17, in output "compartment_id":
│   17:      length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment) > 0 &&
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
╵

╷
│ Error: Argument or block definition required
│
│   on path/to/my.tf line 18, in output "compartment_id":
│   18:      length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments) > 0
│
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid block definition
│
│   on path/to/my.tf line 19, in output "compartment_id":
│   19:      else null
│   20:   )
│
│ A block definition must have block content delimited by "{" and "}", starting on the same line as the block header.

How should I write this instead?

I haven't tested the following snippet, but your expression might be simplified by using the try function:
output "output_value" {
  value = try(
    data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id,
    null
  )
  description = "This is the output value"
)

Explanation:

try evaluates all of its argument expressions in turn and returns the result of the first one that does not produce any errors.


You probably want the ternary expression in terraform, so something like this:
output "output_value" {
  value = length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment) > 0 && length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments) > 0
  ? data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id
  : null
  description = "This is the output value"
)


The syntax you've written seems to be a Python-style conditional experession, but Terraform's language borrows C-style conventions rather than Python-style conventions, so Terraform conditional expressions use a different syntax that is based on C conditional expressions.
Interpreting what you wrote as if it were intended for Python, I believe the valid Terraform equivalent would be:
  value = (
    length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment) > 0 && length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments) > 0 ?
    data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id :
    null
  )

Notice that C-style (and therefore Terraform-style) conditional expressions have the clauses in a different order than Python. Python uses TRUE-RESULT if PREDICATE else FALSE-RESULT, while C and Terraform use PREDICATE ? TRUE-RESULT : FALSE-RESULT.
